# How to set the options of a dynamically created lightning:select?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningselect

I'm using a `$A.createComponent` call to create a `lightning:select` component and in the "success" part of the callback trying to set the select options.

The "Generating Options on Initialization" section of the [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) documentation suggests that:

```
var opts = [
     { value: "Red", label: "Red" },
     { value: "Green", label: "Green" },
     { value: "Blue", label: "Blue" }
];
component.set("v.options", opts);
```

should work but I am getting this error:

> Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'options' of component
>   'markup://lightning:select {1:12;a}' is not visible to
>   'markup://c:wizGenericDetails {1:6;a}'.

reported in a "Sorry to interrupt" dialog. Seems to be blocked by design...

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or on other ways to get options set?

**PS**

Bizarrely turning off debug mode as suggested in [Enable Debug Mode for Lightning Components causes an error when using  on a lookup field](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eaxfQAA) stops the error report but not managing to get the options set so far.

Comment: I'm going to submit a Feedback to the documentation team. You should, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by this [DouglasCAyers/sfdc-lightning-picklist-field-component](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-lightning-picklist-field-component), a workaround that appears to work (and not be sensitive to debug mode being enabled) is to dynamically create this component that iterates over the options:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="name" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="label" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"/>

    <lightning:select name="{! v.name }" label="{! v.label }" value="{! v.value }">
        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{! v.options }">
            <option value="{! option.value }">{! option.label }</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>

</aura:component>
```

If there is a way to avoid this level of indirection and have cleaner code I would move to it and accept the answer.

Comment: This works for me in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox.  In Firefox, the picklilst options do not display.  Thoughts?

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer Nothing comes to mind; see what is going on in Firefox via the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 7):

To set the options, you need to set the component's *body*. Intuitive, no? Here's a demo for you:

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponents(
        [
            [
                "lightning:select", { label: "Select List", name: "list1"}
            ],
            [
                "option", { value: "Option 1", label: "Option 1" }
            ],
            [
                "option", { value: "Option 2", label: "Option 2" }
            ]
        ],
            function(components) {
                components[0].set("v.body", [components[1], components[2]]);
                component.set("v.body", components[0]);
            }

        );
    }
})
```

---

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    {!v.body}

</aura:application>
```

Comment: I've expanded the code in the question to be clearer. The example I was looking at sets a JavaScript array in `v.options`; I think the `v.body` makes sense when setting nested components. Am trying to keep the code simple by not having to create components for the options.