# How to create a lightning select component dynamically with iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This question is similar: [How to set the options of a dynamically created lightning:select?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199922/how-to-set-the-options-of-a-dynamically-created-lightningselect)

but none of the solutions nest the iteration component inside another component..

like so:

Inside Controller:

```
someFunction(cmp, event, helper) : {
    $A.createComponents([
            [
                "lightning:select", { 
                    "aura:id":"selectPicklist",
                    "name":"selectPicklist",
                    "label":"Value",
                    "required":"true",
                    "messageWhenValueMissing":"Did you forget to select a field?",
                    "value":"-- None --"
                    }
            ],
            [
                "aura:iteration", {
                    "items":"{!v.picklistValues}",
                    "var":"picklistValue",
                    "value":"{!picklistValue}",
                    "text":"{!picklistValue}"
            }]
        ],
        function(components, status, errorMessage){
            if (status==="SUCCESS"){
                var selectCmp = components[0];
                var iterationCmp = components[1];
                selectCmp.set("v.body", iterationCmp);
                cmp.set("v.inputValueComponent", selectCmp);
                console.log(cmp.get("v.inputValueComponent").get("v.picklistValues"));
            }
            else if (status==="INCOMPLETE"){
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
            }
                else if (status==="ERROR"){
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);        
                }
        }                    

       );    
}
```

Inside Component

```
<aura:attribute name="inputValueComponent" type="Aura.Component">

<aura:attribute name="picklistValues" type="String[]" default="one, two, three"/>
```

Comment: and what seems to be the problem you are facing, errors if any?

Comment: adding to @glls comment - please share also the whole markup

Answer (score 0):

```
function (pill) {
   var body= component.get("v.body");
   body.push(pill);
   component.set("v.body", body);
}
```

You might have to use push to create components in iteration like above.